# How to provide voice synthesis on my website?

Tags: python, django, text-to-speech, flask-restful

I have a python program which can take as an input a text file and some parameters, and give as output a file mp3. I would like to let people try the system on my website, for small sentences.

I thought I could put the python program on a cloud server and create a API with Flask-Restful, and then call this API with my website which is made with Django Framework. I can't afford a GPU server, so it will take a few seconds/minutes to generate the mp3 file. I can't make a POST request that long, can I?

The thing is, I don't know if this is an appropriate method, is there an easier way to do this ? I just want to install my tts system on a web server, and be able to call it from my website. I didn't found any documentation or tutorial that helped me...

Tell me if my problem is not clear enough,

Thank you for your help

Comment: Make a POST request, *immediately* return a response. Handle the synthesising in a *background task*. Let the client check with GET requests occasionally whether it's done yet. (Or use WebSockets to *push* a notification when it's done.)

Comment: For background tasks, people often use Celery with Python: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html